# Unable to install pycrypto, error "TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, mingw, pycrypto

I have MingW and I am on Windows 10 with Python 3.5.

I have done every thing guides say to do.

Do any of you know how to fix this?

Comment: pycrypto is compatible with Python 3.5, so the problem looks to be with your code, not with pycrypto. How are you installing it?

Comment: pip install pycrypto @Blender